# How to set up autoCompleteTextView in dialog in Kotlin? I am fetching the data from firebase and using that to populate the autocomplete suggestions

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

** This is what I have tried till now. I am creating a list of items from firebase and using that I want to populate autoCompleteParticularName from the dialog. The dialog is popping up but there is no response. My autocompleteAdapter is fine as when I initialized it from the `addNewParticularBtn.setOnClickListener`, then it is responding but I don't want that as I want to update the contents from `onStart()`.
I request help, I am very new to Android Development. **

```
       package com.sushant.quickbills.activity
    
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.View
    import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
    import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
    import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
    import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
    import com.sushant.quickbills.R
    import com.sushant.quickbills.data.AutoCompleteParticularNameAdapter
    import com.sushant.quickbills.data.ITEMS_FIELD
    import com.sushant.quickbills.data.ITEMS_NAME_FIELD
    import com.sushant.quickbills.model.Item
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_new_bill.*
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.pop_up_new_particular.view.*
    
        enter code here
    
    class NewBillActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
        private lateinit var dialogBuilder: AlertDialog.Builder
        private lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog
        private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
        private val itemList = arrayListOf<Item>()
        private lateinit var addNewParticularView: View
        private lateinit var autoCompleteParticularName: View
        private lateinit var autoCompleteParticularNameAdapter: AutoCompleteParticularNameAdapter
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_bill)
    
            //Initialise the variables:-
            database = Firebase.database.reference
            auth = Firebase.auth
            addNewParticularView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_new_particular, null, false)
            autoCompleteParticularName = addNewParticularView.choose_new_particular_name_pop_up
            autoCompleteParticularNameAdapter =
                AutoCompleteParticularNameAdapter(this, ArrayList(itemList))
            dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(addNewParticularView)
            dialog = dialogBuilder.create()
    
            //Set up Adapters
            (autoCompleteParticularName as AutoCompleteTextView?)?.setAdapter(autoCompleteParticularNameAdapter)
    
            //Set up click listeners
            addNewParticularBtn.setOnClickListener {
    
                //Show the dialog
                dialog.show()
            }
        }
    
        override fun onStart() {
            //Item Listener for autocomplete suggestions and fast response
            val currItemRef =
                database.child(ITEMS_FIELD).child(auth.currentUser!!.uid).orderByChild(
                    ITEMS_NAME_FIELD
                )
            val itemListener = object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    itemList.clear()
                    for (child in snapshot.children) {
                        val item = child.getValue(Item::class.java)
                        if (item != null)
                            itemList.add(item)
                        autoCompleteParticularNameAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
    
                }
    
                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    Log.w("Error", "loadItemList:onCancelled", error.toException())
                }
            }
            currItemRef.addValueEventListener(itemListener)
            super.onStart()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to set a list of items to the adapter before you invoke:

```
autoCompleteParticularNameAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply:

I tried doing this but still autocomplete is not working:
`autoCompleteParticularNameAdapter.itemList = ArrayList(itemList)`
 `autoCompleteParticularNameAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`